# How to share data between mobile safari and a webview on the same domain (client side only)

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, local-storage, web-sql, frontend

On **iOS**:
Is it possible to share data on the client side between a page on mobile safari and a page on a WebView (native app) ?
Both pages on the exact same domain.

So far i tired webSQL and localStorage and they seem to keep the data in a separate DBs even though its the exact same link.

I dont mind using WebSQL/indexDB, localStorage, cookie, appCache, *Kung Fu*, whatever!

Your help is highly appreciated :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can share data on the client side between Mobile Safari and an app embedding an `UIWebView`. Indeed, they are two apps hosted in different sandboxes. (For general information about sandboxing, read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)). If this were possible, you could have your app compromise Safari security, which is definitely not desirable.

What you could do is store data on the server side by using cookies. You should provide more details about what you are trying to do in order to provide some concrete example, but the general idea here is that you identify your user session uniquely, then use this unique identifier both from the `UIWebView` and Mobile Safari. Then you can make the `UIWebView` and Mobile Safari communicate like this:

1. from `UIWebView` to Mobile Safari: you can open a URL in Mobile Safari and have that URL encode the user identifier so that Safari will get access to the same user data;
2. in Mobile Safari: use a custom URL scheme (e.g.: "myapp://xxxxxxx") and make your app register itself as a handler for that URL scheme; also, encode the user identifier within the URL so your app knows which data to request.

I hope this hints can give you an idea about how to design your app.

Comment: many thanks. can you elaborate more over how to solve this with cookies and server side? i tired to SET a cookie when having impression on the page in mobile safari and then GET it when having impression on the exact same url on a webview. and the cookie does NOT seem to exist for webview (though on safari it exists) - how can i leverage the server side here?